# how do I terminate a remote desktop session in windows 2012?

Tags: terminal-services

get used to the old world 'terminal session manager' but spent past hour trying to figure out equivalent in windows 2012 r2, all i need is to terminate my session on another server (as it is stuck somehow), google a bit but all I find is to how to setup the service, I just need a simple tool, or even a command line

please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be equivalent tooling built into Win2k12, as it has been partially replaced by the [Remote Desktop Management Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/30/windows-8-windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-management-server.aspx) components, but does not give you a nice listing of sessions  anywhere I've seen.

The easiest way for most users would be to use the Task Manager's User tab. you can usually boot users from there. 
For CLI, You can end the session via the command line, using `quser` and `logoff` (list sessions with quser, and logoff the session id you desire). you can use [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) if you need a remote cli connection to the server.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> quser
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>SomeUser              console             1  Active      none   8/16/2015 5:29 PM
PS C:\Windows\system32> logoff <sessionID>
```

There are many good ideas on [this thread over at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/471224/how-do-i-access-the-list-of-currently-logged-on-users-through-terminal-services#) as well, including power shell commands (Get-RDUserSession/Disconnect-RDUser), [RDC command line utilities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771505.aspx) (qwinsta/rwinsta), and even options to make tsadmin.msc work if copied from an older server.

Or you can try a third party tool like one of these (just examples, not recommendations):

- http://lizardsystems.com/wiki/terminal_services_manager/index
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Administration-Remote-dcbdc028